# Referring to contents of folder 1 to folder 2

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, vbscript, directory, virtual-directory

I wish to offer my website in different languages and still keep everything on the same domain. Subdomains is not an option, unfortunately. I want to be able to tell people to go to a subfolder to choose the language of their wish.

**For example:**
Go to http://www.example.com/es/ to use the Spanish version or go to http://www.example.com/sv/ to use the Swedish version.

I want to build the website from one place, so all the code is located in the `base` folder. All the folders I create in the website (like "es", "sv" and so on) just needs to reference to the `base` folder. How do I do that in ASP Classic (VB)?

My folder structure looks something like this:

```
/base/
    default.asp
    join.asp
    ...
/es/
    -- Get code from the base folder --
/sv/
    -- Get code from the base folder --
...
```

I have searched throughout Stackoverflow but I can't seem to find the answer to this one. I hope someone can help me solve this!

Answer (score 0):

You can [add a virtual folder in IIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/cc771804%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) that points to your /base/ folder. Create one folder for every language you want to support.
Virtual folders are like Windows shortcuts, just a link to a different location on the harddisk (or even on the network). This way you can add folders for every language, and they all point to the /base/ folder.
If your virtual folder has a global.asa file, it becomes an *application* in IIS and you can overrule the default global.asa in it. However, in your case just adding virtual folders would do the trick.
Hope this helps,

Erik